# Android jobScheduler won't stop with jobFinished(params, false)

Tags: java, android, service, android-jobscheduler

I'm tring to create a jobService. Here is what onStartJob() looks like.

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartJob");
    Log.d(TAG, "Params= " + params.getJobId());
    param = params;
    jobFinished(params, false);
    //startAsync();
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
     Log.d(TAG, "onStopJob");
    return false;
}
```

Here is the code that is supposed to start the job.

```
public void startJobScheduler(){
    Log.d(TAG, "inside startJobScheduler");
    Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
    Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();


     mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler)context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );
     JobInfo.Builder job = new JobInfo.Builder(111, new ComponentName(context, JobSchedulerService.class));

     job.setPeriodic(60000);
     Log.d(TAG, "before mJobScheduler.schedule(job.build())");
     if( mJobScheduler.schedule( job.build() ) <= 0 ) {
         Log.d(TAG, "job schedule failed");
     }
    Log.d(TAG, "333");
}
```

I can not get it to stop.  It just keeps firing every 1-5 mins. I put jobFinished(params, false) in onStartJob() and commented out the task to try to kill it off right after it starts, but it just keeps firing. It seems jobFinished() fires something, as onDestroy() is called and my service gets destroyed, but then another job comes in with the same ID and starts it all back up.

I have BIND_JOB_SERVICE in the manifest like every example shows.

Any ideas on why jobFinished(params, false) doesn't seem to kill the setPeriodic(60000)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well I figured it out if anyone else has this problem.

jobFinished() won't stop the periodic time you set from continuing.  It just tells the job that you are finished, to release the wakelock, so Android doesn't have to kill the job off forcefully.

What I had to do was recreate the jobScheduler in my service and call cancelAll().  You could also apparently call cancel(job_id).

```
jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)this.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );
jobScheduler.cancelAll();
```

Comment: Tom's answer below should be the accepted one. You are creating a periodic job and using it as a one-shot, which doesn't make sense as there are ways of doing it correctly.

Also, you are canceling ALL jobs you might have scheduled, not the one that you wanted.

Comment: definitely call `cancel(int)` as `cancelAll()` will, as expected, cancel all scheduled jobs associated with your app (probably not what you'd want)

Answer (score 17):

You have specified that a job is run periodically (every 60 seconds), so every 60~ seconds a new job is created and executed.  `jobFinished()` is specific to a job, and simply indicates that it is done executing.  You haven't cancelled anything.

Your (currently) accepted answer works for cancelling your scheduled job, but if all you want is a job that executes within 60 seconds and then stops, you should ommit `setPeriodic()` and use `setOverrideDeadline(60000)` instead.  The job will run within 60 seconds and no more will be scheduled after it.

Comment: `setOverrideDeadline(3000)` but it keeps on repeating after a certain period on oreo ? What could be the reason..i havent used `setPeriodic` ?

Answer (score 2):

I was using multiple JobService, and to stop one specific Job, I used the id of job to cancel the job.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static void stopMyJob(Context context, int jobId) {
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    scheduler.cancel(jobId);
}
```

First I checked if the current job is active by or not, using the following function

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static boolean isJobActive(Context context, int jobId) {
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    boolean hasBeenScheduled = false;
    for (JobInfo jobInfo : scheduler.getAllPendingJobs()) {
        if (jobInfo.getId() == jobId) {
            hasBeenScheduled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return hasBeenScheduled;
}
```

While starting the job, I have the id passed to jobInfo as:

```
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(jobId, componentName);
```

The same `jobid` I used to stop the job by calling my function `stopMyJob(context, jobID)`.

In most of cases, it's important to stop the current job and start the job again from beginning, if it's already running, for thais I used my both functions mentioned above as:

```
if (isJobActive(activity, ANNOUNCEMENT_JOB_ID)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job will cancel as already exist");
    stopMessagingJob(activity, ANNOUNCEMENT_JOB_ID);
    }
    startMyJob(activity, ANNOUNCEMENT_JOB_ID);
```

My `startMyJob(context, jobId)` looks like:

```
    private static void startMyJob(final Context context, final int jobId) {
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class);
                JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(jobId, componentName)
                        .setPersisted(true).setPeriodic(TWENTY_MINUTES).build();
                JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
                if (JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS != resultCode) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "Job failed to start");
                }
}
```