# Start and stop job scheduling

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have a jobscheduler code which is working quite well. I want to start and end scheduling through start and stop buttons. Once the scheduling works in the background, how can I stop it and vice versa? I didn't find the way to stop scheduler anywhere. cancelAll() only cancels the pending jobs but the scheduler does works again.

Main class

```
public class LiveTrack extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_track);

        //start scheduling
        startLiveTrackBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                ComponentName jobService =
                                new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MyJobService.class.getName());
                JobInfo jobInfo =
                                new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService)
                                        .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000L)
                                        .setExtras(bundle)
                                        .build();
                int jobId = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);

                if(jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)>0){
                }else{
                    Log.e("status","failed");
                }
            }
        }

        //stop scheduling
        endLiveTrackBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //how can I stop scheduling here until the start button is clicked again??  
                jobScheduler.cancelAll();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

JobService class

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService{

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        //some work
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check this link might be helpful you https://stackoverflow.com/a/38088823/7589424

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but as I stumbled onto this post while searching

Here's a solution for Lollipop+

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            with (context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE)
            as JobScheduler) {
                cancel(MyWorkerService.JOB_ID)
            }
        }
```

The alternative for earlier versions is to register a receiver and call "stopSelf" from within it

Answer (score 0):

You can stop JobService (after scheduler it) inside the job class "MyJobService"
by calling onStopJob(jobParameters)... but not from the view (Activity or fragment).